# Match all records in array in return if record exists MySQL query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two table in database.
1) tbl_lab_checkup
2) tbl_lab

tbl_lab has all the records of laboratories and tbl_lab_checkup has all the records o checkup that lab provides.

Following are the fields in tables

```
1) tbl_lab_checkup
-- labcheckupid (pk)
-- labid (fk)
-- checkupid (fk)
-- cost
-- discount

2) tbl_lab

--  labid (pk)
-- labname
-- labarea (fk)
```

I have 'areaid'=1 and 'checkupid' in array which I contact with "," (1,2).

What I want is to get all the lablist available in areaid=1 who provides all the checkup in an array (1,2)

I tried following query But Im getting wrong result.

```
SELECT tlc .* FROM tbl_lab_checkup tlc
INNER JOIN tbl_lab lb ON 
tlc.labid = lb.labid
WHERE 
tlc.checkupid IN (1,2) AND lb.labarea=1
GROUP BY lb.labid
```

It return result even if lab provides only one id in array. Anyone have solution for this.

Check fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c674/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have building this query then you can add the having clause like following:

```
SELECT tlc .* FROM tbl_lab_checkup tlc
INNER JOIN tbl_lab lb ON 
tlc.labid = lb.labid
WHERE 
tlc.checkupid IN (1,2) AND lb.labarea=1 
GROUP BY lb.labid 
having count(tlc.checkupid) = 2;
```

Here `having count(tlc.checkupid) = 2;` the value `2` is the count of your elements in `tlc.checkupid IN (1,2)`.

And if you'd like `distinct tlc.checkupid`, you could switch the `having count(tlc.checkupid) = 2` to `having count(distinct tlc.checkupid) = 2`;

Comment: Will it work in all scenario ? I mean what if lab2 has 1 common and another checkup which is not in array ? will it give same result ?

Comment: Yes, it should, do you have test data?

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing one common and another checkup not in array. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/788c6/2.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally go with the suggestion above by vinodadhikary, but another option would be to use one JOIN per check:-

```
SELECT lb.*
FROM tbl_lab lb
INNER JOIN tbl_lab_checkup tlc1 ON tlc1.labid = lb.labid AND tlc1.checkupid = 1
INNER JOIN tbl_lab_checkup tlc2 ON tlc2.labid = lb.labid AND tlc2.checkupid = 2
WHERE lb.labarea=1
```

This will work when you want all the tbl_lab_checkup record details

Answer (score 1):

User this code to get your desired result in CI:

```
$this->db->select("tbl_lab.*");    
$this->db->join("tbl_lab_checkup","tbl_lab_checkup.labid = tbl_lab.labid");   
$this->db->where("tbl_lab.labarea","1");
$find="FIND_IN_SET('1,2','tbl_lab_checkup.checkupid')";
$this->db->where($find);
$this->db->get("tbl_lab");
```